# Correct offset of specific section PE

Tags: portable-executable

I want to know if my calculations are correct.
I know the following:

```
AddressOfEntryPoint(of PE)
ImageBase(Of PE)
VirtualAddress of section i want
```

so  the offset (in file) of     this section is                                                                                                            `offset = ImageBase - VirtualAddress`

Is this correct? If not ,please explain how I calculate offset of the section.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `PointerToRawData` somewhere in there? Look in the specifications.

Comment: I got RawDataSize, but not pointer to raw data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pefile` module.[here](http://code.google.com/p/pefile)

```
for section in pe.sections:
  print section.PointerToRawData
```